# how do i make simple calculator process infinite as opposed to writing a new code everytime

Tags: python, calculator, infinite-loop

Hello this is my school mini project a pyhton calculator, i was hoping it could be reviewed professionaly and lines i would need to work on be pointed out.

I also have been trying to make the calculator infinte so i do not need to write a new line of code everytime i want the user to be able to calculate a new value, could that be pointed out.

I have tried using while loops but everytime i try to run it nothing happens but pyhcharm does not show an error, so i have stuck to if statements but its exhausting writing a new line of code every time i want a new calculation to happen.

Code:

```
Phasea = float(input("Enter first variable: "))

Phaseb = float(input("Enter second variable: "))

dashboard = input("Input Arithmetic Operator (+,-,/,*): ")

if dashboard == "+":

    print(Phasea + Phaseb)

elif dashboard == "-":

    print(Phasea - Phaseb)

elif dashboard == "/":

    print(Phasea / Phaseb)

elif dashboard == "*":

    print(round(Phasea * Phaseb))

elif dashboard == "":

    print("Ending Program")

else:

    print("Ending Program")

# Phase2 Had to write this in place of a while loop to calculate a third value:

PhaseA = input("Do you have more digits to calculate Y/N: ")

if PhaseA == 'Y' or 'y':

    print("OK")

    PhaseB = float(input("Pls Input your value: "))

    dashboard2 = input("Input Arithmetic Operator (+,-,/,*): ")

    if dashboard2 == "+":

        print(Phasea + PhaseB)

    elif dashboard2 == "-":

        print(Phasea - PhaseB)

    elif dashboard2 == "*":

        print(Phasea * PhaseB)

    elif dashboard2 == "/":

        print(Phasea / PhaseB)

     elif dashboard2 == "":

         print("Ending Program")

     else:

         print("Ending Program")

 elif PhaseA == 'N' or 'N':

     print("Ok, Program Ending.")
```

Is there a way to simplfy this process to a small block of code,
without having to copy, paste and repeat the the same block over
and over again.

Comment: (a) this isn't a code review site; perhaps you want to ask on [codereview.se], and (b) you will need to include your code in your question.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Once you include your code in question, it may be a suitable entry for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as mentioned above. Unless you have a specific programming related problem, this is the wrong site. Please consider deleting your question, or edit it so that it constitutes a programming problem.

Comment: *"I have tried using while loops"* - without you showing us the actual attempts nobody will be able to tell you what you did wrong

Comment: One problem: `if PhaseA == 'Y' or 'y'` always evaluates to "true", as the expression is equivalent to `if (PhaseA == 'Y') or ('y' != '')`. Maybe you have something similar in your invisible `while` loop?

Comment: Ok i have posted it on acode review site instead, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So what you are trying to do is essentially avoid having to check multiple times if the given operator is of a certain type. What I'd do is create a dictionary which has the operation as a key and a function as the value to the corresponding key (operation) like so:

```
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

def subtract(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

def multiply(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

def divide(num1, num2):
    if num2 != 0:
        return num1 / num2
    else:
        raise ValueError("Don't divide by zero it makes no sense.")

operations = {
    '+': add,
    '-': subtract,
    '*': multiply,
    '/': divide
}
```

Then, just ask the user to provide you with their input:

```
operator_char = input("Enter the operator (+, -, *, /): ")
operand1 = float(input("Enter the first operand: "))
operand2 = float(input("Enter the second operand: "))
```

And finally check if the operation exists in your `operations` dictionary, do the calculation and output the result to the screen.

```
if operator_char in operations:
    try:
        res = operations[operator_char](operand1, operand2)
        print(res)
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Error:", e)
else:
    print("Please choose an operation between +, -, *, and /.")
```

You can take this one step further by creating a `Calculator` class with all the operations and be able to call an instance like `.add(7)` or `.div(12)` which is how most people would practice OOP but this essentially has no inherent value unless you are doing high precision calculations with strings instead of floats and integers which is a whole other topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler version.

```
continue_calculate = True
```

continue_calculate is assinged True, so while loop always iterate until we False that statement

```
while continue_calculate:
```

Take user input for operations or as 'exit' to end this.

```
   operation = input("Enter the operation (+, -, *, /) or 'exit' to quit: ")
```

if user will input 'exit' to opeartion statement,programe should False continue_calculate statement,so it will never iterate while loop

```
   if operation.lower() == 'exit':
        continue_calculate = False
```

if user input correct opearion else part will work and get two numbers from user and return relevent output

```
   else:
        num1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))

        # Perform the operation
        if operation == '+':
            result = num1 + num2
        elif operation == '-':
            result = num1 - num2
        elif operation == '*':
            result = num1 * num2
        elif operation == '/':
            if num2 != 0:
                result = num1 / num2
            else:
                result = "Cannot divide by zero."
        else:
            result = "Invalid operation."

        print("Result:", result)
```